# Is there a way to use some sort of wi-fi receiver with the MSI 911-7A74-002 PRO that isn't USB

Tags: motherboard, hardware-rec

I'm planing a budget AAA 60fps [build](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/list/LwtxWX). I wonder if there's anyway to get W-Fi to the [MotherBoard](https://www.amazon.co.uk/MSI-911-7A74-002-Micro-Intel-Motherboard/dp/B01MR248SI?ref_=pe_780071_42221981) and still have (what it seams) the only PCI slot for my video card?

Or are my option only USB or Cable ?

(I'm not fishing for an amazon link for a specific item, but rather is it at all doable)

(I'm also aware of the benefits that Cable brings to the table, I just like to know all my options, and be well backed up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board in question (MSI 911-7A74-002 PRO) has 4 expansion slots:

```
1 x M.2, PCIe/SATA
2 x PCIe 3.0 x1
1 x PCIe 3.0 x16
```

You could use any of these to provide a wireless connection. You'll be using the PCIe x16 slot for graphics, leaving 2 x1 slots for a wireless card, and the option of an M.2 SSD also (Which could also provide wireless, but an x1 PCI-e would be more than sufficient).